# How do I store values from a database into a collection?

Tags: java, collections

```
public String getDataOfpersons() {
try {
    
    String query = "select * from persons";
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println("Records from persons database");
    while(rs.next()) {
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        String age = rs.getString("age");
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + " " + "age: " + age);
    }
    
}catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
return null;
```

}

So I have this part of code and I am reading it from mysql database and I am wondering how could I store object to collection (Name and age) ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to insert data to the database using SQL and JDBC interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a Person class with "name" and "age" fields. Also add the corresponding getters and setters.

Then modify modify your code like this:

```
// change the return type
public List<Person> getDataOfpersons() {
  // create a list to store values
  List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
  try {

    String query = "select * from persons";
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println("Records from persons database");
    while (rs.next()) {
      Person person = new Person();
      String name = rs.getString("name");
      String age = rs.getString("age");
      person.setName(name);
      person.setAge(age);
      personList.add(person);
      System.out.println("Name: " + name + " " + "age: " + age);
    }

  } catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
  }
  return personList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what u looking for without changing the existing signature of the method

```
public String getDataOfpersons() {
    try {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String query = "select * from persons";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Records from persons database");
        while(rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String age = rs.getString("age");
            //System.out.println("Name: " + name + " " + "age: " + age);
            map.put("Name",name);
            map.put("age",age);
           System.out.println(map);
        }

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```